# Paho MQTT JS Client already connected error?

Tags: javascript, mqtt, paho, tizen-web-app

I'm trying to build a Tizen Web Application which connects to an MQTT broker using Paho MQTT JS library.

But every time I run the application I keep getting the following error:

`Error: AMQJS0011E Invalid state already connected.`

Here is my code

```js
/**
 * 
 */

var broker="broker.mqttdashboard.com";
var port=8000;

var client=new Paho.MQTT.Client(broker,port,"myWebClientID_"+parseInt(Math.random()*100,10));

client.onConnectionLost=function (response){
 console.log("Connection Lost: ",response.errorMessage);
}

client.onMessageArrived=function(message){
 console.log(message.destinationName, "--",message.payloadString);
}

var option={
  timeout:3,
  onSuccess: function(){
   client.subscribe('/Aya',{qos:1});
   console.log("Connected to broker");
   
   var message=new Paho.MQTT.Message("Test Message");
   message.destinationName="/Aya";
   client.send(message);
   
  },
  onFailure:function(msg){
   console.log("Connection Failed",msg.errorMessage);
  }
}

function init(){
 client.connect(option);
}

$(document).ready(function(){
 console.log("Document ready");
 init();

});
```

The code snippet works fine when I'm trying to run it on a browser.

Comment: Also please add your config.xml ?

Comment: I looked at the config.xml file and turns out I didn't give the application permission to access the Internet. The error message is unrelated to the MQTT library.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I realized that the error had nothing to do with the MQTT error.

The issue was that I hadn't given the application appropriate privileges, i.e. I did not add the application permission to access the Internet in config.xml and therefore the application could not connect to the broker.

Comment: So How did you fix this error?
I am facing same error but it happen just sometimes..